# Linux cronjob runs 60 times instead of 1 on AWS EC2

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, cron

I have setup a cronjob on the AMI AWS using SSH using `crontab -e`.
I wanted it to run once a day at 11:00PM, so I wrote it like this:

```
* 23 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/public/cronjobs.php
```

My script runs the php script which emails me when it's finished successfully.
The problem is, I am getting 60 emails every time the job runs, which is really horrible. Why would it run 60 times instead of 1?

Appreciate your help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
0 23 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/public/cronjobs.php
```

that is replace the first wildcard which represents the minute with a fixed value, 0.

Asterisk  (*) stands  for "first-last", which means that your cron job will be executed once every minute during hour 23. By changing it to 0 you fix it to execute once only at 23:00 every day.

Answer (score 3):

You got wrong minute set.

```
* 23 * * * // run at every minute of 11 PM (11:00, 11:01)
0 23 * * * // run at 11:00
```